# Floating Label in ASP.NET MVC 5 using @Html.TextBoxFor()

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to know that how I can add floating labels in my ASP.NET MVC 5 Web application. I have searched on the Internet but there is no solution. I want to use @Html.TextBoxFor(), and @Html.LabelFor(), for implementing floating labels. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] to get a better answer to your question. Provide a [example] and show what you have tried till now.

Comment: What do you mean by floating labels?

Comment: floating labels like when i click on textbox the label floats from input field to top of the textbox

Comment: You mean like [Material Design](https://material.io/components/text-fields)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086503/textbox-text-hides-for-floating-label-textbox-style      Something like this but using @textboxfor only in .cshtml of mvc web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some EditorTemplates like

```
@model string

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = " " })
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x)
</div>
```

The Placeholder is required for the correct behavior of the floating.

Additionally I used

```
    ViewContext.ValidationMessageElement = "label";
```

in my _ViewStart.chtml

and some Javascript-Code to correct the validation-appearance with jquery-validation:

```
class Validation
{
    static init = (defaults = {
        highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
            $(element).addClass("is-invalid");
            var $label = $(element).next("label");
            if ($label.length) {
                $label.hide();
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).removeClass("is-invalid");
            var $label = $(element).next("label");
            if ($label.length) {
                $label.show();
            }
        },
        errorClass: 'is-invalid',
        errorElement: 'label',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var label = element.next("label");
            if (label.length) {
                error.insertAfter(label);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    }) => {
        $.validator.setDefaults(defaults);

        $("form").each((idx, form) => {
            var $errors = $(form).find(".field-validation-error");
            if ($errors.length) {
                var errorList = {};

                $errors.each((i, error) => {
                    errorList[error.dataset.valmsgFor] = error.innerText;
                })

                let validator = $(form).validate();
                validator.showErrors(errorList);

                $errors.remove();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm happy with the result